# Trying to find a regexp to use for Tumblr

Tags: ruby, regex, tumblr

I am trying to find a regexp that is capable of grabbing a full tumblr link in ruby.

I have been using this regexp for flickr, foursquare and a few other sites because it easily allows for me to grab all the text surrounding it.

/(?:https?://)?(?:www.)?flickr.com/\S+/g;

But Tumblr, given the name of the user/blog that precedes the .tumblr has me at a loss and obviously doesn't allow me to use this.

http://heywatchthismovie.tumblr.com/

Would love any advice on what to do.

Comment: Please post an actual corpus that shows examples of what should and should not match.

Answer (score 0):

Pattern match on `\w+` to find the subdomain.

```
> s= 'blah blah http://heywatchthismovie.tumblr.com/ blah blah'
=> "blah blah http://heywatchthismovie.tumblr.com/ blah blah"
> s =~ %r{(?:https?://)?(?:\w+.)?tumblr.com/}
=> 10
```